# Read From Kafka using Node and franz-kafka module

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, consumer

I try to read from Kafka using Node and franz-kafka module.

I have followed the example at  https://www.npmjs.com/package/franz-kafka.

I have produced something like the following:

```
var Kafka = require('franz-kafka')

var kafka = new Kafka({
    zookeeper: ['{my zookeeper ip}:2181'],
    logger: console
})

kafka.connect(function () {

    // topics are Streams 
    var foo = kafka.topic('foo')

    // consume with a pipe 
    foo.pipe(process.stdout)

    // or with the 'data' event 
    foo.on('data', function (data) { console.log(data) })


    // resume your consumer to get it started 
    foo.resume()

    // don't forget to handle errors 
    foo.on('error', function (err) { console.error("STAY CALM") })

    }
)
```

When I run my server I receive the following error:

```
assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: number too small
    at toDouble (/home/stefano/TestKafkaNode/node_modules/franz-kafka/node_modules/int53/index.js:49:3)
    at Object.int53.readInt64BE (/home/stefano/TestKafkaNode/node_modules/franz-kafka/node_modules/int53/index.js:62:9)
    at Function.ZnodeStat.parse (/home/stefano/TestKafkaNode/node_modules/franz-kafka/node_modules/zkjs/protocol/znode-stat.js:20:29)
    at GetDataResponse.parse (/home/stefano/TestKafkaNode/node_modules/franz-kafka/node_modules/zkjs/protocol/get-data.js:32:30)
    at Receiver.read (/home/stefano/TestKafkaNode/node_modules/franz-kafka/node_modules/zkjs/receiver.js:91:16)
    at Receiver.streamReadable (/home/stefano/TestKafkaNode/node_modules/franz-kafka/node_modules/zkjs/receiver.js:112:8)
    at Client.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
```

I have searched on google without any result.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Well I have never worked with the franz-kafka module, but with kafka-node. So if this package is also an option I maybe can help you.

Comment: I am considering to use `kafka-node`. I have try to read from more than one partittion without result. can you help me?